# MySQLdb query to Numpy array

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, numpy

So I've tried to follow [What's the most efficient way to convert a MySQL result set to a NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061824/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-covert-mysql-output-into-a-numpy-array-in-pytho) but am still having problems.

My database rows are 57 unsigned integers (Unix epoch plus byte counts for each of 28 switch ports, in and out).

My code looks like:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
import numpy

# get the database connector
DBconn = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', '<Password>', 'Monitoring')

with DBconn:

    # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    cursor = DBconn.cursor()

    # now get the data for the last 10 minutes
    sql = "select * from LowerSwitchBytes where ComputerTime >= (unix_timestamp(now())-(60*10))"
    cursor.execute(sql)

    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        print row
```

So that prints out 10 lines like:

```
(1378151928L, 615983307L, 517980853L, 25355784L, 117110102L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 267680651L, 288368872L, 84761960L, 337403085L, 224270992L, 335381466L, 27238950843L, 549910918625L, 240002569249L, 11167210734L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 222575491L, 335850213L, 223669465L, 339800088L, 310004136202L, 16635727254L, 0L, 0L, 16590672L, 147102083L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
```

But when I change the:

```
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        print row
```

to

```
    A = numpy.fromiter(cursor.fetchall(), count=-1, dtype=numpy.uint32)
    print A
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "min.py", line 23, in <module>
    A = numpy.fromiter(cursor.fetchall(), count=-1, dtype=numpy.uint32)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`np.fromiter` is complaining because it is trying to write a full row of inputs into a single item of the new array. You can work around this using record arrays:

```
A = numpy.fromiter(cursor.fetchall(), count=-1,
                   dtype=[('', numpy.uint8)]*57)
```

If all your records are of the same type, you can then get an array view as follows:

```
A = A.view(numpy.uint8).reshape(-1, 57)
```

Comment: So that mostly works, but since they are bigint numbers, it's numpy.uint32 instead of numpy.uint8 on both lines.  Many Thanks!