# Numpy ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting `Numpy ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence` when attempting to turn mysql data into a numpy array (eventually a list). Originally I wanted to have multiple fields but I've simplified the code to only making a list with one field (integer) for troubleshooting purposes.

I'm new to numpy so I'm not exactly sure what `i4` represents (although docs say it means an integer.... ok). As for the `count`, that seems to refer to the number of fields. However, something on that `fromiter` line is still causing it to hit an exception.

```
import MySQLdb
import numpy

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="x", passwd="x", db="x")
curs = conn.cursor() 
numrows = curs.execute("select id from table")

A = numpy.fromiter(curs.fetchall(), count=numrows, dtype=('i4'))

print A 
ids = A['f0']
```

Traceback:

```
A = numpy.fromiter(curs.fetchall(), count=1, dtype=('i4'))
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: I added the relevant lines. It really doesn't show anything more than the errors I already quoted.

Comment: It does show the line numbers among other useful information. Just copy the complete output to your question.

Comment: There are only 8 lines in this entire script. The fromiter one is the only exception raised.

Answer (score 4):

correction - **to work with a list of tuples from `fetchall`, the `dtype` should produce a structured array**

Looking at the documentation I see that `fetch_all` returns a list of tuples, not a generator.  But that isn't the issue here.  Both are iterables.  The problem is with the dtype. To make a 1d array from a list of tuples, `fromiter` requires a structured, compound, dtype.

This dtype works with a 1 element tuple:

```
In [355]: np.fromiter([(1,)],dtype=[('f0','i4')])
Out[355]: 
array([(1,)], dtype=[('f0', '<i4')])
```

This works with 2 fields (columns)

```
In [356]: np.fromiter([(1,1)],dtype=('i4,i4'))
Out[356]: 
array([(1, 1)],   dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

But these are the same - a plain, non-structured array.

```
np.fromiter([(1,)],dtype=('i4'))
np.fromiter([(1,)],dtype=int)
```

`[(1,)]` is handled the same as `[[1]]`, the input for a 2d array, not the 1d iterable that `fromiter` expects.

---

`np.array` works the same as `fromiter` for the structured cases:

```
 np.array([(1,)],dtype=[('f0','i4')])
 np.array([(1,1)],dtype=('i4,i4'))
```

It also works with `int` (or `i4`), but the result is a 2d array:

```
In [366]: np.array([(1,)],dtype=('i4'))
Out[366]: array([[1]])
```

---

(earlier version)

I can reproduce your error message by giving `fromiter` a `[(1,)]` iterable.

```
In [288]: np.fromiter([(1,)],dtype=int)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-288-ba24373a9489> in <module>()
----> 1 np.fromiter([(1,)],dtype=int)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

`fromiter` wants a 1d input, e.g. `[1,2,3]` (or the generator equivalent).

It's been a while since I worked with `sql`, but my guess is that `curs.fetchall()` gives a iterable of tuples, not an iterable of single numbers.

You need to display (print) `curs.fetchall()` or `list(curs.fetchall())` to see what what is being passed to `fromiter`.

Why are you using `fromiter`?  Have you tried `np.array(curs.fetchall())`?

Let's try a generator expression to better simulate a `fetchall` that generates a tuple:

```
In [298]: np.fromiter((i for i in [(1,2,3)]),dtype=int)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-298-f8fbf106b4d1> in <module>()
----> 1 np.fromiter((i for i in [(1,2,3)]),dtype=int)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
In [299]: np.array((i for i in [(1,2,3)]),dtype=int)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-299-71dd7463b539> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array((i for i in [(1,2,3)]),dtype=int)

TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'generator'
```

This works:

```
In [300]: np.array(list(i for i in [(1,2,3)]),dtype=int)
Out[300]: array([[1, 2, 3]])

In [301]: list(i for i in [(1,2,3)])
Out[301]: [(1, 2, 3)]
```

The simplest way to create a numpy array is with a list - it can be a list of numbers, a list of lists (all the same size) or a list of tuples.

[What's the most efficient way to convert a MySQL result set to a NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061824/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-convert-a-mysql-result-set-to-a-numpy-array) is an earlier discussion of using `fetchall` and `fromiter`.

---

Comment: Fromiter is what I found on google. All I want to do is move mysql data into some lists so I can graph the data.

Comment: In any, let's be clear about what you get from `cur`.  Try to create a basic Python list and display that.  Then we can address making an `np.array`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still looking into it but it would seem as though this would relate to the fact I was only using one field (as a test), but it was actually expecting at least 2 or something. I created a new table with 2 fields of an integer each, to test, and was then able to run this code without an exception.

Comment: I figured out why 2 fields works, but 1 doesn't - `dtype=('i4')` does not produce a structured array, while `dtype=('i4,i4')` does.