# Equivalent of pandas read_sql_query for numpy array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I would like to use something equivalent to pandas "read_sql_query", to load the data from the database into a numpy array, not a pandas dataframe.

In pandas I use something like:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql="select * from db;", con=con, index_col='index')
```

And now I would need a function like:

```
A = read_sql_to_np(sql="select * from db;")
```

where A is a numpy array.

Comment: does this help? [What's the most efficient way to convert a MySQL result set to a NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061824/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-convert-a-mysql-result-set-to-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any dataframe can be converted into a `numpy` array using the `to_array()` method:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3], 
                           'B': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0], 
                           'C': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
>>> df.to_numpy()
array([[1, 1.0, 'a'],
       [2, 2.0, 'b'],
       [3, 3.0, 'c']], dtype=object)
>>> df['A'].to_numpy()
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> df[['A', 'B']].to_numpy()
array([[1., 1.],
       [2., 2.],
       [3., 3.]])
>>> df[['C']].to_numpy()
array([['a'],
       ['b'],
       ['c']], dtype=object)
```

So you can simply use `pandas` and then extract the numpy array from the resulting dataframe.

As [Parfait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59951165/equivalent-of-pandas-read-sql-query-for-numpy-array/59951581?noredirect=1#comment106023109_59951581) points out, you have to be careful about data types when doing the conversion. I left that implicit in the example above, but notice how the first example generates an array with `dtype=object`, whereas the second generates an ordinary floating point array. I think a detailed discussion of data types in `numpy` is beyond the scope of this question though.

Comment: Let me know if there is some reason you need to avoid pandas entirely. But in the vast majority of situations I would recommend this over rolling your own SQL-to-numpy converter.

Comment: @Henry, Remember too a database table most likely resembles a pandas dataframe (columns of varying types) than a numpy array (columns and rows of same type). So naturally, a DB API would be set up for pandas and not numpy.

Comment: BTW - if your database table does resemble a matrix (all types the same), you may not be exercising database normalization!